# how to get a text inside html/text content?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

hi all
I have html/text something like:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
</style></head>
<body><div style="font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt">first text<br><div><br></div><div style="font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 14pt;"><br><div style="font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 12pt;"><font size="2" face="Tahoma"><hr size="1"><b><span style="font-weight: bold;">one:</span></b> second text<br><b><span style="font-weight: bold;">two:</span></b> third text<br><b><span style="font-weight: bold;">three:</span></b> fourth text<br><b><span style="font-weight: bold;">five:</span></b> fifth text<br></font><br>
```

and I want to extract the text named "first text" in the above html content
Note: this html content is not static it's dynamic, so the general idea is to get the first plain text in an html text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup), so you're using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). That's already a good choice ;)

Here's how you could do it with Jsoup:

```
String html = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\"></style></head><body><div style=\"font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt\">first text<br><div><br></div><div style=\"font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 14pt;\"><br><div style=\"font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 12pt;\"><font size=\"2\" face=\"Tahoma\"><hr size=\"1\"><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">one:</span></b> second text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">two:</span></b> third text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">three:</span></b> fourth text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">five:</span></b> fifth text<br></font><br>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
String firstText = document.select(":containsOwn(text)").first().ownText();
System.out.println(firstText);
```

Result:

> first text

#### See also:

- [Jsoup CSS selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: hi BalusC, thanks a lot for the above example, i will try it, but does it work only if the content starts with <html><head>,<body> coz sometimes the content i am working on doesn't have <html><head>,<body> and sometimes the text is not in the body, it's inside a div which i don't know it's location, it's hard i know to find a pattern

Comment: really thanks a lot for your help, and for the quick feedback, i do have one more question though, is that what if i want to get the first div that contains a text (the whole div) to get an output, something like: <div style="font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt">first text<br><div>

Comment: @BalusC, i also want to mention that the text i want to get is not something static, so i want to get the first text which maybe anything and doesn't have a specific pattern.

Comment: You can play around with `Element#text()`, `Element#html()`, `Element#outerHtml()` to see if any suits.

Comment: any ideas how to get the index of third div ?

Comment: Use `get(3)` instead of `first()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SAX styled HTML parser, like [TagSoup](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers/tagsoup).

To do this, initialize the parser with an extended `DefaultHandler` to detect when the first time the `characters(...)` method is called and save the result.

Look to http://sax.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html for some direction in how to setup the parser.

Comment: The HTML may not be properly-formed XML, however, which may cause issues with the parsing.

Comment: Thank you.  Must have see HTML but thought XML.  As you properly pointed out, XML parsing will only work with XHTML variants.  I've updated it to mention TagSoup, a SAX styled HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something fairly simple, look at my [PageScraper class](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/scraping/), which was designed for use on Java ME platforms and so will work pretty much anywhere. Nothing fancy, but an easy way to transform a text stream into tags and non-tags. Does lazy loading of attributes, so pretty quick to use if you're basically ignoring tags.